# Cancel link event of link button while opening up modal dialog

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-modal

I have this current code shown below. I want to cancel this link event (href="#conclusion") and open up the modal I created after clicking the link button (id="linkconclusion") **if name and age inputs are empty.** Please assume I have the modal coded and is working perfectly fine.

Currently, after clicking the link button, modal dialog opens but the page still links to conclusion, i.e link event (href="#conclusion") still happens. Could someone advice on where the problem is with my current code? I am using bootstrap v3 just for additional info. The fiddle for the code below is https://jsfiddle.net/1vznjbos/2/

HTML Code:

```
<input type="text" id="inputname"  placeholder="Input name here">
<input type="text" id="inputage"  placeholder="Input name here">
<a id="linkconclusion" href="#conclusion" class="btn btn-danger">Done</a>  

<div id="conclusion">
   <p id="displayname"></p> 
   <p id="displayage"></p> 
</div>
```

JavaScript Code:

```
var a = document.getElementById("linkconclusion");    
        a.onclick = function displaybiometric() {

            //====== CANCEL href="#conclusion" AND OPEN MODAL =========
            var m1 = document.getElementById("inputname").value;
            var m2 = document.getElementById("inputage").value;
            if (m1 == ""){              
                    $('#linkconclusion').click(function() {                     
                        return false; // cancel the event
                    });                         
                document.getElementById("modalforbio").click();                 
            }
            if (m2 == ""){              
                    $('#linkconclusion').click(function() {                     
                        return false; // cancel the event
                    });                         
                document.getElementById("modalforbio").click();                 
            }

           //===== DEFAULT CODE THAT SHOULD RUN ONCLICK OF LINK BUTTON =====
            var wlname = document.getElementById("inputname").value;
            document.getElementById("displayname").innerHTML = wlname;
            var wlage = document.getElementById("inputage").value;
            document.getElementById("displayage").innerHTML = wlage;

}
```

**Solution**:

I have found a solution to work around this. Simply remove the link event (href="#conclusion") in the link tag and only add it when the conditions are fulfilled.  https://jsfiddle.net/5b00nuee/

Comment: Just use `e.preventDefault()` while handling the click event.

Comment: `return false; // cancel the event` - that’s not the proper way to do that with jQuery’s event handling. Why are you mixing jQuery syntax and plain JavaScript so much anyway?

Comment: Try `<a id="linkconclusion" href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-danger">Done</a>`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I have tried prevent Default but the link event (href="#conclusion") still happens even though inputs are empty. I had found a solution for it though and shared it above.

Answer (score 0):

Updating your `href` to `void(0)` will prevent the default action

```
<a id="linkconclusion" href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-danger">Done</a>
```

**or**

Use `e.preventDefault()` while handling the click event.

```js
var a = document.getElementById("linkconclusion");
a.onclick = function displaybiometric(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  //====== CANCEL href="#conclusion" AND OPEN MODAL =========
  var m1 = document.getElementById("inputname").value;
  var m2 = document.getElementById("inputage").value;
  if (m1 == "") {
    $('#linkconclusion').click(function() {
      return false; // cancel the event
    });
    document.getElementById("modalforbio").click();
  }
  if (m2 == "") {
    $('#linkconclusion').click(function() {
      return false; // cancel the event
    });
    document.getElementById("modalforbio").click();
  }

  //===== DEFAULT CODE THAT SHOULD RUN ONCLICK OF LINK BUTTON =====
  var wlname = document.getElementById("inputname").value;
  document.getElementById("displayname").innerHTML = wlname;
  var wlage = document.getElementById("inputage").value;
  document.getElementById("displayage").innerHTML = wlage;

}
```